# Code Output not in the Ouput/Debug Panel rather Terminal in VSCode Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run Java Programs (beginner) in VS Code. Whenever I try to run the program, it runs in the Terminal Panel. Any way I can change it so the end result is always in the Output/Debug panel.

It makes things a lot easier and cleaner.

I have been looking on the forums and the VSCode site to see if someone has already answered this but it hasn't been yet.

Answer (score 6):

You might be using debugger for java as an extension. You can modify the extension settings within the extension manager. Look for Debugger for Java and press on the settings icon. A list will appear. Press extension settings. There you can change the console specification to what you want. Set it to internalConsole. Go back to your code and run. You will see that it will show up on the Debug Console instead of the integrated terminal.

Answer (score 5):

you could try to add `"console": "internalConsole"` in your **launch.json** like :

```
"configurations": [
           {
             "type": "java",
             "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - App",
             "request": "launch",
             "mainClass": "com.test.maven.App",
             "console": "internalConsole",
             "projectName": "my.app"
           }
         ]
```

then it will show in `Debug Console`

Answer (score 0):

On the Visual Studio Code website there is a page that explain the process of doing just that: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging

To resume it:
1. [Download an extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) to make it easier
2. `Run/Debug` the app (or method) by clicking on the `Run | Debug` over the said method. For the whole app click the `Run | Debug` over the `main()`. You can also press `F5` to start the whole thing

Things should display in the `Debug` pane now.

Bear in mind that in order to run `Java` application you have to run the `JVM` which is a progrma in itself. That is why the terminal is usually brought up if you select `Run`.